# NoSuchFieldError _hostname_ - FTPSClient Java with Interpreter

Tags: java, eclipse, ftp, interpreter

I am trying to get the FTPSClient Example from Apache running (See here:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_2_2/src/main/java/examples/ftp/FTPSExample.java)

In Eclipse, this example code works fine and I can upload my files to a server. When I try to compile my code within the Interprete,r which can run normal java sourcecode also, it still works. But when I start my compiled program, I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: _hostname_
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:266)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:226)
org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient:163)
org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient:250)
FTPSExample.doMyUpload(FTPSExample.java:93)
```

The last "sentence" is Class with my self named method. In line 93, I just try to connect to a Server:

```
this.ftps.connect(this.server);
```

Eclipse and my Interpreter are both taking the same classpath where my commons.net.jar is placed (3.6). So I really dont know, why this error appears.
If you need to see the full class, I can post it here. But I did no changes to the original Example from Apache.

Thank you, Louis

Answer (score 0):

Probabry, you are using an old versin of Commons Net jar or `SocketClient` class. The field variable `_hostname_` has been introduced since Commons Net version 3.4. See also [this history](https://github.com/apache/commons-net/commit/65302de24316b21a3955265203c60cf663067743#diff-a200cef3c4245acc8be677a2ddff2fea). The field is defined in abstract class `SocketClient` and used by an extended class `FTPSClient`. If both new version of `FTPSClient` and old version of `SocketClient` is used, then `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: _hostname_` is thrown.

Comment: Okay, so how do I fix that ? In my Classpath there is only the newest commons-net-3.6.jar. I recompiled everything, but the error still remains.

Comment: Is there `SocketClient.class` in `WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/commons/net/`? If yes, please backup (& remove) it to other location. If no, please try to replace the jar file downloaded from [official site](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi).

Comment: So, i did what you said, removed and backuped the SocketClient.class and recompiled my FTP Client Class and my EBUS program. When I start my EBUS program, the same error occures. What can I do now ?

Comment: Update: I cant compile my Eclipse Class, because the SocketClient.class is missing - what now ?

Comment: Okay, i think i found the mistake: There was another .jar File in my classpath, which had an SocketClient.class (older version of it maybe). I check that out now.

Comment: Okay, there is another library that contains the SocketClient.class file. But it is not the same one as its used in commons.net library. Is there a way to tell my interpreter to use the other library in Java ?

Comment: So here is the solution: Because the second .jar library has been loaded before the other one, its class has been used (just because the .jar was named "a.jar" and the other one "b.jar", so a.jar was loaded first). Just rename your files for the right order and there you go.